# Why my page doesn't show the newest data

Tags: caching, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I write an app with google app engine. It is a simple blog system. If I delete a piece of blog, the page didn't refresh as I wish. It still present the blog that has been deleted.But if I refresh the page after that, it will present in the correct way. I though it was the problem of cache. I have been working on it for serveral days. Could anyone teach me how to fix it? Thanks very much.

```
class BlogFront(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        val = self.request.get("newPost")
        #get all the pages
        posts = Post.all().order('-created')
        #stop the cache in the browser
        self.response.headers["Pragma"]="no-cache"
        self.response.headers["Cache-Control"]="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0"
        self.response.headers["Expires"]="Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00"
        self.render('front.html', posts = posts)

    def post(self):
        #press the delete button
        operatorRequest = self.request.get('Delete')
        articleId = operatorRequest.split('|')[0]
        operator = operatorRequest.split('|')[1]
        key = db.Key.from_path('Post', int(articleId), parent=blog_key())
        post = db.get(key)
        db.delete(post.key())
        self.redirect("/")
```

Comment: This page that you want refreshed, is it in a browser window?  How would it know that it should refresh itself?

Answer (score 2):

I assume redirect to `/` is handled by `BlogFront` handler. Seems you're hitting datastore eventual consistency.

[Google App Engine Datastore: Dealing with eventual consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633835/google-app-engine-datastore-dealing-with-eventual-consistency)

[GAE: How long to wait for eventual consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261099/gae-how-long-to-wait-for-eventual-consistency)